# what does {} mean in hook state initialization react

Tags: react-hooks

I have seen a hook state initalize in this way.

```
const colors = [
  { value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' },
  { value: 'blue', text: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC' },
  { value: 'purple', text: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
]
const [{ formBasicUsageExample }, setState] = useState({ formBasicUsageExample: colors[0] })
```

This looks strange to me. I never see people use {} to surround a state here. How to understand the {} around formBasicUsageExample? What is the effect here

I understand the concept of destructuring, and it looks it may be deal with that. But I dont get it in such context(normally in para list). Appreciate if a basic example provide to understand it.

Comment: Its destructuring the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Javascript Object destructuring

You are setting the state variable value with `{ formBasicUsageExample: { value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' }}`
Then using javascript object destructuring to only fetch the value of `formBasicUsageExample` key.

```
const colors = [
    { value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' },
    { value: 'blue', text: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC' },
    { value: 'purple', text: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  ]
  const [{ formBasicUsageExample }, setState] = useState({ formBasicUsageExample: colors[0] });
```

Here, formBasicUsageExample contains :

```
{ value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' }
```

If there is no `{}` provided,

```
const colors = [
    { value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' },
    { value: 'blue', text: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC' },
    { value: 'purple', text: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  ]
  const [formBasicUsageExample , setState] = useState({ formBasicUsageExample: colors[0] });
```

Here, formBasicUsageExample contains :

```
{ formBasicUsageExample: { value: 'ocean', text: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9' }}
```

Simple Javascript example:

```js
let person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
const {firstName} = person;
console.log(firstName);
```

Comment: without {} , why not this formBasicUsageExample = { formBasicUsageExample: colors[0] }

Comment: without {}, it is `formBasicUsageExample = { formBasicUsageExample: colors[0] }`.

with {}, it is `formBasicUsageExample = colors[0]`.

Comment: you clear my doubt, thanks

Comment: Could you also upvote my question? since it may help other to read it coz we have already put effort to make this question valuable to read.

Answer (score 0):

What's being done is technically [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It's just being done in a confusing manner. What `formBasicUsageExample` refers to on the left hand side of the assignment is the value in the returned object associated with that key, so in our case it will be whatever the value of `colors[0]` is.